# Add comma after the last curly brackets in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I would like to add a comma `,` after the last `}` in a shell script.

From:

```
[
  {
    "targets": [ "localhost:32804", "localhost:32805" ],
    "labels": {
      "env": "local",
      "job": "instances"
    }
  }
]
```

To:

```
[
  {
    "targets": [ "localhost:32804", "localhost:32805" ],
    "labels": {
      "env": "local",
      "job": "instances"
    }
  },
]
```

Comment: if you are dealing with JSON, then the expected output isn't a valid JSON entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this, with `sed`. Using the `-z` flag to pretend that lines are terminated by ASCII character 0 (`NUL`) rather than newline - so that `sed` sees the entire input file as a single long line.

```
sed -Ez 's/(})([^}]*$)/\1,\2/' <filename>
```